# sql server query for current timestamp at timezone

Tags: sql-server, timezone

i need the query to get the current time stamp with "US/Central" time zone in sql server.

can you suggest me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you plz show your time format. is it MM/DD/YYYY??

Comment: Unless he is incompetent enough to store dates or times in a string field that absolutely does not matter.

Comment: yes .MM/DD/YYYY format

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the application.

SQL Server timezone handling is not up to tasks like this - never was planned for that. Most people handle this by storing data in UTC on sql server and having the front end deal with timezone calculations.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39421/how-to-handle-timezone-properly-in-sql-server

has a decent explanation of the options. In a modern SQL Server version you could write support functions for that in .NET.

But at the end the requirement says: The application design is bad.

Answer (score 0):

As @TomTom suggested you should do this in your application. Otherwise, if you know the number of hours offset that your local time is from US/Central time, you can use the [`SWITCHOFFSET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb677244.aspx) keyword. For example:

```
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIMEOFFSET), '-04:00')
```

Comment: in my application user should get the time according 'US/Central' time zone from any part of the world. number of hours i can't change every time

Comment: Then do it in the application. It's generally a good idea to store all your times in a standard time zone (I use UTC, but I'm biased as that's my local time anyway!)

Comment: CAN YOU BRIEFLY EXPLAIN HOW TO DO IT?

Comment: No, I can't do it briefly.